# Can Quantum observables be modeled as real functions on the phase space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematical-physics, phase-space, observables

In the context of justifying the failure of modeling quantum observables in the 'more natural' way as real functions on the phase space (i.e. similar to the mathematical image modeling classical observables) and somehow justifying the use of the framework of Hilbert space and operators . In the following talk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODAngTW8deg
(see 1:00 to 4:00)

Alain Connes argued that phase space and real functions on it cannot support the co-existence of continuous real observables (i.e. those whose image has the continuum cardinality) and discrete ones (i.e. whose image is finite or countable) by the following argument :
Denote by $X$ a phase space and suppose the existence of a discrete observable $D$ and a continuous $C$ one on $X$. We then have necessarily that $X$ has the continuum cardinality. But then we will get at least a real value $\lambda$ in $\mathbb{R}$ which has an (even 'continuous') infinite number of pre-images by $D$. (i.e. a continuous infinite number of states which corresponds to this value..) so the values $\lambda$ will have an 'infinite multiplicity' and he said that this is impossible !
Can anyone help what is the impossible in this situation ? I mean do we have something in the classical paradigm which says that an observable value $\lambda$ (i.e. A measured value of an observable) cannot be hitten  an infinite number of times ? (i.e. there cannot be an infinite number of states in the phase space having the value $\lambda$ as a measure of a fixed observable $A$). Is it a physical problem or a mathematical one ?

Comment: The problem is strictly mathematical, but I'm not qualified to answer it, as I have had trouble understanding the speaker for over four decades. Indeed, naively, every point in phase space is a state, but in the [phase-space formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation) of QM this is not so, as in certain cases a real function observable must further satisfy a *-genvalue equation w.r.t. a single (Wigner) function describing the state, where these values are actually discrete. This comports (subtly!) with his identification of observables as operators  in Hilbert space...

Comment: I see you have asked the very same question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590878/can-we-model-quantum-observables-as-real-functions-on-the-phase-space).  The facile answer here is that observables ***are*** continuous real functions in phase space, but the conceit/ implicit assumption that states are points in phase-space is thoroughly unwarranted.

Comment: Sir @CosmasZachos, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: my question was in the sens that 'is that impossible to find a mathematical image of QM I mean as a phase space and real function on it modeling the physical observables so that we go to the 'firstly appearing weird' formulation as linear spaces and operators and their spectra ? I mean we can consider real function (not necessarly contiunuous) as our QM observables. I m looking to understand why this generates I you said a Mathematical problem.

Comment: It is impossible to map continuous phase-space points to a discrete spectrum, as AC says, but there is a monstrous fallacy in *assuming* such points amount to QM states, "as in classical mechanics". But *nobody* has seriously argued this is warranted, before AC. I can imagine mathematicians are stunned by a freakish straw man, but, really now...